# Why does starting a process in the background prevent me from recalling previous commands in the command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmd.exe

I'm running asynchronous command prompt commands in `cmd` on Windows 7 64-bit and for some reason it affects my ability to recall previous commands just after I run them; for example:

I might run something like:

`start /B rmdir /Q /S .\some_massive_directory`

And next I try to press the up arrow to recall the text of the previous command..but nothing happens...is this because whatever data structure is holding my commands is locked by the process I sent to the background, or is it because I am using a network mapped drive to run my command on?

Comment: Works as expected here using some basic testing.  When in that state, what happens when you hit "Down" once?

Comment: Nothing, that's the problem...well this is an old system which has been through quite a few system administrators and motherboards...maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Why are you using `start /B`? (This is **not** sent to the background) This uses the current window so execution will wait until executed. So you would not need the `start /B`. And how many cmd.exe have you open. In the settings you probably have 4 buffers for `DOSKEY`. When you do a `start` (and it is the fifth) maybe you'll loose the buffer of the last/first cmd.

Comment: And you can use `doskey /history` to see the history. So you can check if it's really empty.